# Flask : Decorator to test query string arguments

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I begin with Flask and try to create the best code possible. For some simple route, I would like to check if some required arguments are present.
At this time, I create this decorator

```
def validate_qs_arguments(arguments):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            for argument_name in arguments:
                if request.args.get(argument_name) is None:
                    abort(400, "'{name}' argument is missing".format(name=argument_name))
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, fn)
    return decorator
```

I can use it like this :

```
@validate_qs_arguments(arguments=["pid", "datastream"])
```

It works fine. But I'm trouble than Flask doesn't provide a build-in function/decorator to do the same thing.
Is it exists a better to do that ? A build-in flask decorator/function ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIK, flask leaves you with the choice to roll your own decorators for your business logic. You should take a look at the [flask_restful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#argument-parsing) project if you're building a REST API service in flask. It provides the `reqparse.RequestParser` class for parsing and validating request data among other niceties.

Answer (score 1):

*Flask doesn't provide a build-in...* Flask is a micro-framework that was built around a plug-in approach. If you want more out of it, use [extensions](http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/) (Flask-restful is one of it as it was said in comments), or [python marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/), or other lib, or write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Decorator func:

```
def check_form_key(key_list:list):
    def real_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if request.form is None:
                return Result(False, Error("FR"))
            not_exist_key = []
            for key in key_list:
                if key in request.form:
                    continue
                else:
                    not_exist_key.append(key)

            if len(not_exist_key) > 0:
                return Result(False,"this keys not exist {0}".format(not_exist_key))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator
```

Usage:

```
@check_form_key([“name”,”code”])
def check():
   pass
```

Comment: This needs more context - an explanation of the code, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

```
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if "log" in session:
             return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
             return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return decorated_function
```